# Flex : how to pretty print JSON.stringify?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm using the built in JSON package with Flex 4.6, how do you get it to nicely format the output, e.g. indent with 4 spaces, put each object on a new line etc.?

Comment: I don't understand what output you are trying to format.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The last param is used to insert spaces:

```
JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
```